Como uso el nuevo outlook en C#
Usar nuevo outlook en C#
Hola comunidad, tengo una pregunta, alguien sabe usar el nuevo outlook en C#, ya que me preocupa que algunas de mis aplicaciones desaparezcan e estado usando esta librería:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
Pero estoy preocupado que de use mi app y no funcione por el nuevo outlook alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo mantener la compatibilidad o algo?
Gracias.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/one-outlook
